# Declare a generic collection

Tags: c#, generics

I have 3 classes (`A`,`B`,`C`) and have to implement a storing method for all of the classes so I thought that of using a generic list like `List<T> = new List<T>();` but it doesn't allow me to use it.

I would like the method to be like this:

```
class Bascket
{
   List<T> list= new List<T>();

   public void addToBasket(T value)
   {
      list.Add(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that A, B and C are items which you wish to store in the Basket object, you should create a base class of those items, and declare generic collection as collection of base class, i.e.

```
public interface IBasketItem
{ 
    /* put some common properties and methods here */
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class A : IBasketItem
{ /* A fields */ }
public class B : IBasketItem
{ /* B fields */ }
public class C : IBasketItem
{ /* C fields */ }

public class Basket
{
    private List<IBasketItem> _items = new List<IBasketItem>();

    public void Add(IBasketItem item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public IBasketItem Get(string name)
    {
        // find and return an item
    }
}
```

You can then use Basket class to store all your items.

```
Basket basket = new Basket();
A item1 = new A();
B item2 = new B();
C item3 = new C();
basket.Add(item1);
basket.Add(item2);
basket.Add(item3);
```

However, when retrieving items back, you should use common interface, or you should know of which type the object actually is. E.g:

```
IBasketItem myItem = basket.Get("cheese");
Console.WriteLine(myItem.Name);
// Take care, if you can't be 100% sure of which type returned item will be
// don't cast. If you cast to a wrong type, your application will crash.
A myOtherItem = (A)basket.Get("milk");
Console.WriteLine(myOtherItem.ExpiryDate);
```

Comment: that should be the correct way, but the interface has 6 properties fildes in it and A has 4, B has 4 and C has 4. If I implement an interface I must use all 6 properties declared in that interface, I don't know a way around

Comment: Which interface has 6 properties? Create your own interface with only the things you need, as in example above. Which interface did you try to use?

Comment: My custom interfaces IBasketItem has 6 properties and class A only uses 4 and B uses 4 and C uses 4, if I only implement on 4 properties it gives me error like "Error does not implement interface member"

Comment: Then this is an interface for something else. Create interface IItem, which will have only items which are A, B and C have in common. If they have none in common, make an interface without members, and inherit it from your A, B and C classes.

Comment: In that case use an interface with no properties. This is called a [marker interface] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and is used in cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `T` is not declared. You can add a generic parameter to your class for this to work:

```
class Basket<T>
{
   List<T> list= new List<T>();

   public void addToBasket(T value)
   {
      list.Add(value);
   }
}
```

This allows you to use your class like this:

```
var basket = new Basket<string>();
basket.addToBasket("foo"); // OK
basket.addToBasket(1); // Fail, int !== string
```

Comment: but it doesn't do what I want because basket can only take class A and not B or C

Comment: like var basket = new Basket<A>(); basket.addToBasket(A) but B and C can't be added to the same List

Comment: A,B,C should implement interface Iabc and you should constrain your generic with it

Comment: @XandrUu The code you just posted will work with alexn's answer.

Comment: @XandrUu If you want to accept multiple times, give them a common interface, then add a generic constraint to your basket: `class Basket<T> where T : IFace`.